# DNN: Change from address in emails coming from private messaging functionality

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-module

I am using dnn "[member directory module](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&ved=0CFYQtwIwAw&url=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fuAPvdTQn60&ei=WQuNUo-wGsmGrgeuj4GoCg&usg=AFQjCNHYQ6lKPzJyZwekR5vAk5dEhzUY1Q&sig2=MqYec2BnTGO4wls84tWZlg&bvm=bv.56643336,d.bmk)". It allows site users to send messages to other users. These messsages appear to receiver as private message and receiver also gets an email for the message. This message has site admin email id in from address. Now my requirement is to change senders emailId address in such a way that email may appear to be coming from sender and not from site admin.

Sounds confusing I guess:

- Consider a DNN site having site email id as siteadmin@blabla.com
- Say this site has two users: A(a@BlaBla.com) and B(b@BlaBla.com)
- Now A sends private message to B
- B receives email at b@BlaBla.com from siteadmin@BlaBla.com
- Now my requirement is that B should receive email from b@BlaBla.com rather than siteadmin@BlaBla.com

I checked and found member directory module makes post request to below DNN internal service API for this

> http:///DesktopModules/InternalServices/API/MessagingService/Create

Code for this API I found on BitBucket with user Jamie Clayton under "MessagingServiceController", this API in turn calls "SendMessage" method which I found under "DotNetNuke.Services.Social.Messaging.MessagingControllerImpl".

Checking all this I just found that this thing is creating queue and email is sent somehow else probably a service and I am stuck a bit on where to check next.

Please suggest. Any pointers pointing towards classes that send this email would be great. Also please suggest if this could be achieved some other way.

Comment: Set the reply-to address to `a@blahblah.com`. This scenario is not unique to either .net or private messaging.  Google reply-to header. Be aware that many mail servers are cautious when the domain doesn't match the from address, as this is a common backscatter technique for spammers.

Comment: yes I am aware of this. But still thought if its possible to do, it could be an option. My root problem is people replying to such messages and those replies reaching to site admin rather than person intended.